# How do I use the given vector equation to resolve vector $p$ into a parallel and perpendicular component?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am working on the following problem:
[image]
Here's what I've done so far:
[image]
[image]
I know that dotting the first component with q should equal one to show that it is parallel and dotting the second component with q should equal to 0 to show that it is equal to zero to show that it is perpendicular. I haven't been getting those two results. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parallel component is obtained by the scalar product of $q$ with the dot product of $p$ and $q$, after normalization of $q$.

Hence
$$\left(p\cdot\frac{q}{\|q\|}\right)\frac{q}{\|q\|}=\frac{p\cdot q}{\|q\|^2}q$$
i.e.

$$\frac{(3,-2,-1)\cdot(2,-2,3)}{2^2+(-2)^2+3^2}(2,-2,3)=\frac{7}{17}(2,-2,3).$$

The perpendicular component is the difference

$$(3,-2,-1)-\frac{7}{17}(2,-2,3).$$

If you multiply that by $q$, you get $7-7$.

Comment: With that being said, are my initial calculations for splitting $p$ correct?

Comment: @AugieJavax98: there is enough information in my answer for you to check. At first sight, $14\ne 13\cdot2$, but I noticed a sign error in my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. By the way, you cubed 3. Isn't it supposed to be squared?

Comment: @AugieJavax98: I am fixing the typo**s**.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that dotting the first component with q should equal one to
>   show that it is parallel

Not in general:
$$
p_\parallel \cdot q 
= \lVert p_\parallel \rVert \lVert q \rVert \cos \angle(p_\parallel, q)
= \lVert p_\parallel \rVert
$$

> and dotting the second component with q
>   should equal to 0 to show that it is equal to zero to show that it is
>   perpendicular.

Check your calculation:

$$
(p \times q)_1 = -6/\sqrt{17} - (-1 \cdot -2/\sqrt{17}) = -8 / \sqrt{17}
$$

etc.

Comment: Will go through again and check. Thanks